# socket API: accept method didn't set sockaddr_in structure

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I'm developing client-server software. On server's side I use this code:

```
int listener_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

if (listener_socket < 0)
{
   perror("opening socket error");
   return;
}

/* set option for reuseaddr */
int mtrue = 1;    
if(setsockopt(listener_socket,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR,&mtrue,sizeof(int)) != 0)
{
    perror("setsockopt error");
    return;
}

struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;


bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
bzero((char *) &cli_addr, sizeof(cli_addr));

serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

/* bind socket */
if (bind(listener_socket,(struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
{
    perror("binding error");
return;
}

/* start listening */
listen(listener_socket,connections_limit);      

int newsockfd;

/* infinite cycle */
while(1){
      newsockfd = accept(listener_socket,(struct sockaddr*) &cli_addr,&clilen);
 ...
 }
```

So my code blocks in `accept()` method and waiting for the new connection. When client connects, accept method returns correct non-negative socket descriptor (i can communicate with client using this descriptor) but it doesn't fill `cli_addr` structure. It remains zeroes. Why it happens?

Comment: `clilen` is both input and output parameter. Are you initializing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i forgot this line before accept:

```
clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
```

Comment: @FromReview: It is perfectly valid and acceptable for a questioner to post an answer to their own question. And yes, this answer does provide a suitable solution: "*Why accept does not fill cli_addr? Because I forgot to initialize clilen!*".